# Generic search implementation in EF Core

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to implement a generic search method which can be used with all entities of DB.

```
public static object HandleSearch(object objList, string searchText)
{
    Dictionary<string, object> ht = null;
    List<Dictionary<string, object>> returnList = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();
    var a = objList as ICollection;

    object data = null;
    Type tp = null;
    foreach (object obj in a)
    {
        ht = (Dictionary<string, object>)obj;
        foreach (string key in ht.Keys)
        {
            data = ht[key];
            tp = data.GetType();

            if (tp == typeof(DateTime))
            {
                if (((DateTime)data).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss").Contains(searchText))
                {
                    returnList.Add(ht);
                    break;
                }
                else if (data.ToString().ToLower().Contains(searchText.ToLower()))
                {
                    returnList.Add(ht);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return returnList;
}
```

I should call this as

```
var x = _service.GetAll(eo);
var c = GeaUtility.HandleSearch(x, "29/02");
```

When I try it gives me "unable to cast from List to List<Dictionary<string, object>>.

How can I solve? Any ideas?

Comment: Just to clarify you receive a list of objects (of any type) and search them for any given string?

Comment: Yes. I'm trying to implement a global search.

Comment: Where the error is thrown?